# How to find user login logout time in WSO2 Identity Server?

Tags: session, wso2, wso2-identity-server

In WSO2 identity server, how can we find login logout time of all user's?
The Identity Server is using MySQL database.

What SQL statement can retrieve this information from the database
Or Which tables will contain this information?

Comment: What is the version of IS that you use?

Comment: Do you want to get the last login/logout time or login history of a user?

Comment: Anuradha, l am looking for Login history of all users.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider just the Identity Server product only, you can track the user login details, but not the logout details. This is because when the user logs out and session expires, details in the database will be deleted immediately or eventually. Below tables contains these information.

```
IDN_AUTH_SESSION_META_DATA
IDN_AUTH_SESSION_APP_INFO
IDN_AUTH_USER_SESSION_MAPPING
```

And [this](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/session-mgt-rest-api) API is available to retrieve single user sessions and terminate them.

However you want the user login **and logout** details, you have to go for the analytics side. Documentation [here](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/analytics) explains the integration with analytics product and how to use it.